# Selenium select dropdown option

Tags: java, select, selenium

I'm going to say the dreaded words - i'm fairly new to java

But I can't find my answer online in the most obvious places so I'm going to ask the question here

The program i'm testing is a customer database, when you select the Country drop down box, other fields may become mandatory
Amongst those fields is "State"
This field can either be a free text or a drop down box

So i've created an if statement that lets me input free text if the conditions for a state drop down box is not met:

```
if (selenium.isElementPresent("xpath=//*[@id='state']/option[2]"))
{selenium.select("xpath=//select[@id='state']/option","index=2" );}

else    {checkfield("xpath=//td[contains(.,'State/Province:')]/
preceding-sibling::td[contains(.,'*')]", 
        "xpath=//*[@id='address.state']",
        state1);}

<td>
<!-- begin state drop down menu -->
<select id="state" name="address.state">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<!-- end state drop down menu -->
</td>
```

My question may be a very basic one and you guys can probably already see where my code fails

I want to choose option 2 of the drop down box if a drop down box is present, otherwise enter a string which has been declared in the free text box

up until now i've only ever used selenium.select for selecting a label which has specific text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try doing it using labels instead?

selenium.select("state", "label=Alaska")

You're likely to know what the values will be unless new states get added (seems unlikely)

Comment: That's what I've been using so far but if another country is selected, the state drop down values will change. If a drop down box is created I want it to select the second option (missing Please Select). Is there any way to change the "label" in the above select to an "option" or "id" and choose 2?

Comment: @Omz yes you can just change it to be:
`selenium.select("id=state", "index=2");` I believe? Give that a go anyhow.

Comment: You should have the following options when handling drop downs: 
OptionID, Option Label, Option Index, Option Value.

Comment: Cheers goose, was going round in circles, was quite late and wasnt analysing it properly. You hit the nail on the head, working properly now! Thanks, now i have solve my other drop down problems...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: **Upgrade to Selenium WebDriver**

Selenium 1.0 is just an undead.

That's the way to do it with WebDriver:

```
if(stateDropdown.isEnabled()&&(!stateField.isEnabled())){

    Select state = new Select(stateDropdown);
    // state.selectByValue("Illinois");
    state.selectByIndex(2);


}else if(stateField.isEnabled()&&(!stateDropdown.isEnabled){
    stateField.sendKeys("Salzburg");
}
```

Isn't it pretty?

Comment: Thanks for the reply frank, I will be upgrading to selenium 2 once I've got a grip on selenium 1. Back to the question- you've actually selected a value and sent it, I don't want to do that, I want to send the second option in the list (whatever it may be as the state options will change when different countries are selected). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: From my point of view it's inadvisable to start with using an old Project without any future. If you have the chance to select your setup better choose the Ferrari and feel overwhelmed at the beginning than drive the Volkswagen a lifetime... Added the answer (select the second)

Comment: +1 for upgrade to WebDriver (and clean concise example to answer question)

Comment: For the time being, is there an answer for this for selenium 1.

Comment: Also, off topic but the reason I didn't start using webdriver was because my tests have to be done on an ie browser and for some reason, using webdriver didn't locate the xpaths or CSS correctly (selected the next radio tab every time). I found it too unstable on the site I was working in where as selenium 1 has pointed to every path correctly. Any tips on why this could be would be great as I lost 2 days trying to find out

Comment: never had that problem but notice that the InternetExplorerDriver is quite unstable. In general, try to use IDs to locate the WebElements.
You can test your tests with FF and switch to IE afterwards..

Comment: of course WebDriver is not perfect either (yet) but it's still improving and a much better approach from day one